# How to get records after a certain time using SQL datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

If I have a datetime field, how do I get just records created later than a certain time, ignoring the date altogether?

It's a logging table, it tells when people are connecting and doing something in our application.  I want to find out how often people are on later than 5pm.

(Sorry - it is SQL Server.  But this could be useful for other people for other databases)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For SQL Server:

```
select * from myTable where datepart(hh, myDateField) > 17
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(SQL.80).aspx.

Comment: This only accepts whole hours, not a "certain time" and shouldn't be the accepted answer as-is.

Answer (score 7):

What database system are you using? Date/time functions vary widely.

For Oracle, you could say

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
  WHERE TO_CHAR(THE_DATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '23:59:59';
```

Also, you probably need to roll-over into the next day and also select times between midnight and, say, 6am.

Comment: This one won't return the rows from 1/2 second before midnight.  Why not just >= '17:00:00'.

Comment: @Joe: actually >= '17:00:00' or even >= '17' should also work, I think

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, this would be

```
where time(datetimefield) > '17:00:00'
```

Comment: how do I do this but not ignoring the date? i need sql (mysql) query that lists events 1 hour before, so if its the same date and 1 hour till a start time sort of thing?

Comment: @JayMee just compare the datetime column to a datetime string like '2022-09-09 15:50:00'.

Comment: yeah i dont know how give example please!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I can think would be: don't use a DateTime field; well, you could use a lot of DATEADD/DATEPART etc, but it will be slow if you have a lot of data, as it can't really use an index here. Your DB may offer a suitable type natively - such as the TIME type in SQL Server 2008 - but you could just as easily store the time offset in minutes (for example).

Answer (score 1):

For MSSQL use the CONVERT method:

```
DECLARE @TempDate   datetime = '1/2/2016 6:28:03 AM'
SELECT  
    @TempDate as PassedInDate,  
    CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @TempDate, 108) < '06:30:00' then 'Before 6:30am'
        ELSE 'On or after  6:30am'
    END,
    CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @TempDate, 108) >= '10:30:00' then 'On or after 10:30am'
        ELSE 'Before 10:30am'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it.

```
select myfield1, 
       myfield2, 
       mydatefield
  from mytable
 where datename(hour, mydatefield) > 17
```

This will get me records with a mydatefield with a time later than 5pm.

Comment: You may also want to think about the real early hours of the morning and include anything before 6am or something...

Comment: In this case, I don't care, but I can see that would be something to consider in other cases (I'm just trying to find out when people are generally out, so we can schedule some db maintenance).

Answer (score 0):

Another Oracle method for simple situations:

```
select ...
from   ...
where  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM my_date) >= 17
/
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm#SQLRF00639

Tricky for some questions though, like all records with the time between 15:03:21 and 15:25:45. I'd also use the TO_CHAR method there.

Answer (score 0):

In Informix, assuming that you use a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND field to hold the full date, you'd write:

```
WHERE EXTEND(dt_column, HOUR TO SECOND) > DATETIME(17:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND
```

'EXTEND' can indeed contract the set of fields (as well as extend it, as the name suggests).

As Thilo noted, this is an area of extreme variability between DBMS (and Informix is certainly one of the variant ones).